# Split string based on given words from list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I am trying to find a way to split string based on given words only.

Also the new list should respect the word order from the initial string (text)

Few examples below :

```
def split_str_from_words(words, text):
    return ???

split_str_from_words(["hello", "world"], "helloworldhello")
split_str_from_words(["hello"], "helloworldhowareyouhello")
split_str_from_words(["hello", "how", "are", "you", "world"], "helloworldhowareyouhello")
```

Based on the 3 examples above, the function should return :

```
["hello", "world", "hello"]
["hello", "worldhowareyou", "hello"]
["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you", "hello"]
```

I have no clue how to do it ( I tried with functions such as split but so far nothing works as expected.

I have idea how to create my own algorithm but I wonder if there was any built-in functions that I can use for this case.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

So far I am able to detect all my words occurrence / position / word 
length

It could be really useful to keep the order of the words and slice strings.

```
import re

def split_str_from_words(words, text):
    for word in words:
        positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, text)]
        print(word, positions, len(positions), len(word))

    return ""
```

Comment: What if words were something like: `hello`, `he` and `lo`, `loan`, `hell` and `and` and the input was `loandbeholdhellolo` kind of thing?

Comment: for this kind of situation, it will depend from the given words order, for example should start first with hello > hell > he)

Comment: I am thinking of first get all the position of words and store it and remove them from string until my list of word is finish. So I can reuse the position of the substrings to recreate the order in my new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the proposed example, [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) joining all words to be matched with `|` should do.

```
def split_str_from_words(l, s):
    m = re.split(rf"({'|'.join(l)})", s)
    return [i for i in m if i] # removes empty strings (improvements are welcome)
```

---

```
import re

split_str_from_words(["hello", "world"], "helloworldhello")
# ['hello', 'world', 'hello']

split_str_from_words(["hello"], "helloworldhowareyouhello")
# ['hello', 'worldhowareyou', 'hello']

split_str_from_words(["hello", "how", "are", "you", "world"], "helloworldhowareyouhello")
# ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'hello']
```

Comment: That's work perfectly, very smart use of re.split 
It also respect the order (if I put hello, hell or hell, hello it will affect the result) Many thanks!!